# AngularJS controller unit tests - injecting services

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

A hopefully simple question about AngularJS unit testing. I have a controller using a simple service (adapted from angular-seed project)

**services.js:**

```
angular.module('myApp.services', []).value('version', '0.1');
```

**controllers.js:**

```
function MyCtrl1($s, version) {
  $s.version = version;
}
MyCtrl1.$inject = ["$scope","version"];
```

This works great im my app. However, I have trouble creating the controller in unit test frame work. I can't figure our how to inject 'version' service (or create instance) and pass it to $controller() factory - I assume that's what I want to do?! Here's the bare bones spec:

**controllerSpec.js**:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  // how about version service?
  ctrl = $controller(MyCtrl1, {$scope: scope, /* version: <where from?> */});
}));

it('Version should be 0.1 ...', function() {
    expect(scope.version).toBe('0.1');
});
```

Running the test harness yields:
**>test.sh**

*... failed (3.00 ms): Error: Error: Unknown provider: versionProvider <- version
            Error: Unknown provider: versionProvider <- version*

I have tried various things with $injector/$provider and module() but to no avail. I'm sure the answer is simple, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 57):

just add `beforeEach(module('myApp.services'))` to your describe block. This will load the services module with the "version" service into the test injector and that will make it available to your test.

Comment: Thank you! That was simple. It didn't occur to me having two beforeEach() calls - interesting.

Comment: By the way, is it a good practice to write unit tests for a controller with a service dependency ? Or it is better to create the mock for the service, and then write one test for the controller and one for the service ?

Comment: @e.gluhotorenko I find it easier to do the second option, test the controllers using a mock service. Then test the services separately. I found Tim Buschtöns article about [how to use mocks in Jasmine](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/03/27/mocks-in-jasmine-tests/) really helpful. Made setting up mocks for services easy and overall my tests more flexible.