# Karma: how to unit test the filter with dependencies?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angularjs-injector

I'm trying to unit test filter which has dependency on another service. I've read many answers regarding this problem but nothing solved mine.
I use karma/Jasmine

the conf as follow

```
  // Karma configuration
  // Generated on Thu Nov 26 2015 07:47:24 GMT+0100 (Västeuropa, normaltid)

 module.exports = function(config) {
 config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'
],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
 'lib/angular.min.js',
 'lib/angular-mocks.js',

 'test.js',
 'app/js/services/*.js',

 'app/js/filters/*.js'

  ],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-          preprocessor
 preprocessors: {
  },
```

my application  as follow

```
// filter

var app=angular.module('app.filter',[]);

app.filter("filterName",['serviceName',function(ServiceName){
return function(input1,input2)
{
//some code
}]);


// service

 var app=angular.module('app.service',[]);
 app.service("serviceName",      [$log,$windows,$route',function($log,$windows,$route){
//some functions

}]);
```

the test

```
   describe('test filter with services dependencies',function()
{

     beforeEach(module('app.service')); 
      beforeEach(module('app.filter'));

      var FilterNAMe, ServiceNAMe ;


 beforeEach(inject(function(_ServiceNAMe _,_FilterNAMe_) // i get error here
 {
  FilterNAMe = _FilterNAMe_;
  ServiceNAMe= _ServiceNAMe_;

 }));

  it('',function()
   {
    //some test;

  });



  });
```

and I get the following error

> error:[$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/$injector/unpr?=%24serviceNameProvider
>
> Error: Declaration location at windows.inject.angular.mock.inject

Comment: why two different modules for a service and a filter?

Comment: they are located in different modules, so I need to invoke both of them in my beforeEach method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first it is not needed to module( app.service),where the dependency service is located

otherwise, use provide function to provide the service when invoking the current module

```
var $filter,  FilterNAMe ;
beforeEach(function () {

angular.mock.module("app.filter", function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('serviceName');
        });
});
```

then inject the filter

```
    beforeEach( inject(function ( $filter) { //<-- Get the filter provider

    FilterNAMe =$filter('FilterNAMe ',{});

    }));
```

see the answer
[Injecting dependent services when unit testing AngularJS services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238490/injecting-dependent-services-when-unit-testing-angularjs-services)