# Angularjs is not able to find my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am using angular-mock to inject my controller for unit testing. I am failing to do so since I keep getting the following error.

```
 [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: PatientRecordsControllerProvider <- PatientRecordsController
```

Here is my code setup -

```
    (function () {
angular.module('patient_profile', ['ngRoute']);
    })();


(function () {
    var PatientRecordsController = function () {

    };

    angular.module('patient_profile').controller('PatientRecordsController', PatientRecordsController);
})();
```

And my test case

```
    describe('PatientRecordsController:unit-testing', function () {

    beforeEach(module('patient_profile'));

    it('timeline should be an array', inject(['PatientRecordsController',
        function (controller) {
            //Cant do stuff
        }
    ]));

});
```

**UPDATE** The same procedure works perfectly fine with services. How come?

Comment: I sounds like it is having problems with the provider not the controller.

Comment: Hmm, controller is a provider isnt it ? Well what is the solution?

Comment: did you forget to include the script to `patient_profile` module in the test?

Comment: @KhanhTO The script gets loaded fine. Could it be the ordering of the scripts?

Comment: Was the answer not useful at all?

Comment: @dmahapatro It would be great if you could add why we need to instantiate controllers explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller has to be instantiated using `$controller` service. Isn't the below format of test cleaner?

```
describe('PatientRecordsController:unit-testing', function () {
    var controller;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('patient_profile');

        inject(function(_$controller_){
            controller = _$controller_('PatientRecordsController', {});
        });
    });

    it('timeline should be an array', function(){
        //DO STUFF using controller
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh boy! That worked like a charm. But your answer still doesn't determine why my method is flawed. Could you please explain that too ?

Comment: As I said earlier, you need `$controller` service to instantiate the concerned `controller` which you have not used in your approach. Look at `inject` above in the answer.

Comment: But the same thing works if its registered as a service. How is that working?

Comment: I could be sounding dumb :(

Comment: You have a valid question. Yes, you do not need to inject a service it is used in controller because services are singleton and is automatically provided/injected once the controller is instantiated in tests.

Comment: I dint quite understand. Could you explain a little more in detail please? I have updated the questions with the query also.

Comment: I hope [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551986/angularjs-controller-unit-tests-injecting-services) will make it clear for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50623/discussion-between-tushar-and-dmahapatro)

Comment: Got it. Controllers are not singletons so there is no point caching them. Thus they are never instantiated?

Comment: Yes. They have to be instantiated on demand. Anyways, that should be a separate discussion altogether, different from this question.